# How to config GenericObjectPoolConfig?

Tags: java, connection-pooling

Currently, I am using apache commons pool2. But I couldn't find any document related to how to config GenericObjectPoolConfig properly. Like maxIdle, maxActive, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis and so on. Does anybody have some general rules?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official documentation as below

I like the configurable parameters documented in pool 1.x :
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html

However, in pool2 documentation can be read from the method level documentation :
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html

For the later part of the question regarding the 'general rules', the pool (BaseObjectPoolConfig) comes with the defaults configured, so you can test and then fine tunes specific parameters based on your app behavior.

Hope this clarifies, else you can ask specific questions.